# C++11: Variadic Homogeneous Non-POD Template Function Arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11

How would you write a template function that takes a variable number of homogeneous non-POD function arguments in C++11?

For example suppose we wanted to write a min function for any type that defines the less than "operator<" as follows:

```
// pseduo-code...

template<class T...>
T min(T x1, T x2, ..., T xn)
{
    T lowest = x1;

    for (T x : {x2,...,xn})
       if (x < lowest)
           lowest = x;

    return lowest;
}
```

The above is illegal C++11, how would you write it legally?

Comment: The above is not illegal (assuming the `...`s are just a pseudocode way of saying "more stuff here").

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'm guessing by the title that those aren't pseudocode; the OP needs variable arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Homogeneous? **Just use `std::initializer_list`**.

```
template <typename T>
T min_impl(std::initializer_list<T> values)
{
    return *std::min_element(values.begin(), values.end());
}

...

return min_impl({8, 5, 4, 1, 6});
```

(As [@Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762531/c11-variadic-homogeneous-non-pod-template-function-arguments/9762849#comment12423060_9762849) noted, this is the equivalent to [std::min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) in the standard library.)

If you don't like the extra braces, make a variadic template that forwards to the initializer list implementation:

```
template <typename... T>
auto min(T&&... args) -> decltype(min_impl({std::forward<T>(args)...}))
{
    return min_impl({std::forward<T>(args)...});
}

...

return min(8, 5, 1, 4, 6);
```

Comment: This is also the same as [std::min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)) (maybe it should be stressed that whether its a POD type or not doesn't make a difference).

Comment: It should be noted that this will not work for move-only types. You cannot move out of an `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 4):

First, variadic templates don't include a way to say 'a variable number of arguments of a single type'. When you use variadic templates you get a parameter pack which is a set of zero or more arguments, each with a possibly unique type:

```
template<typename... Ts> void foo(Ts... ts);
```

the `...` token only has defined meanings for these parameter packs (and vararg functions, but that's beside the point). So you can't use it with non-parameter packs:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T... t); // error

template<typename T> void foo(T t...); // error
```

Second, once you have a parameter pack, you can't just iterate over the parameters the way you're showing with the range-based for-loop. Instead you have to write your algorithms in a functional style, using parameter pack expansion to 'peel off' parameters from the parameter pack.

```
// single argument base case
template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << t;
}

template<typename T,typename... Us>
void foo(T t,Us... us) {
   foo(t) // handle first argument using single argument base case, foo(T t)
   foo(us...); // 'recurse' with one less argument, until the parameter pack
    // only has one argument, then overload resolution will select foo(T t)
}
```

Although variadic templates don't directly support what you want, you can use `enable_if` and use the 'SFINAE' rule to impose this constraint. First here's a version that without the constraint:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
T min(T t) {
    return t;
}

template<class T,class... Us>
typename std::common_type<T,Us...>::type
min(T t,Us... us)
{
    auto lowest = min(us...);
    return t<lowest ? t : lowest;
}

int main() {
    min(1,2,3);
}
```

And then apply `enable_if` to ensure that the types are all the same.

```
template<class T,class... Us>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T,typename std::common_type<Us...>::type>::value,
    T>::type
min(T t,Us... us)
{
    auto lowest = min(us...);
    return t<lowest ? t : lowest;
}
```

The modified implementation above will prevent the function from being used any time the arguments aren't all exactly the same according to `is_same`.

You're probably better of not using these tricks if you don't have to. Using an initializer_list as KennyTM's suggests is probably a better idea. In fact if you're really implementing min and max then you can save yourself the trouble because the standard library already includes overloads that take an initializer_list.

---

#### How does `is_same<T,typename common_type<Us...>::type>` work?

Because there's a single argument version of `min()` the variadic version is selected only when there are two or more parameters. This means that `sizeof...(Us)` is at least one. In the case where it is exactly one, `common_type<Us...>` returns that type single type, and `is_same<T,common_type<Us...>>` ensures that the two types are the same.

The variadic implementation of `min()` calls `min(us...)`. So long as this call only works when all the types in `Us...` are the same we know that `commont_type<Us...>` tells up what that type is, and `is_same<T,common_type<Us...>>` ensures that T is also that same type.

So we know that `min(a,b)` only works if `a` and `b` are the same type. And we know that `min(c,a,b)` calls `min(a,b)` so `min(c,a,b)` can only be called if `a` and `b` are the same type and additionally if `c` is also the same type. `min(d,c,a,b)` calls `min(c,a,b)` so we know that `min(d,c,a,b)` can only be called if `c`, `a`, and `b` are all the same type, and additionally if `d` is also the same type. Etc.

Comment: If you enforce all types to be the same, what is the use of `common_type`? Also, `common_type<Us...> == T` can be true without all types in `Us...` being the same as `T`.

Comment: @pmr common_type is part of how the argument types are forced to be the same. All the types in `Us...` will be the same, so the common_type will be that type. This is provable via induction.

Comment: @pmr I added a bit on how that condition works to ensure all the types are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little convoluted but that's what you get if you want
heterogeneous arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename F, typename T, typename Arg>
auto fold(F f, T&& t, Arg&& a) 
  -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Arg>(a)))
{ return f(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Arg>(a)); }

template<typename F, typename T, typename Head, typename... Args>
auto fold(F f, T&& init, Head&& h, Args&&... args) 
  -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(init), std::forward<Head>(h)))
{ 
  return fold(f, f(std::forward<T>(init), std::forward<Head>(h)), 
              std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}

// polymorphic less
struct p_less {
  template<typename T, typename U>
  typename std::common_type<T, U>::type 
  operator()(T&& t, U&& u) const {
    return t < u ? t : u;
  }
};

// heterogeneous arguments possible
template<typename Head, typename... Args>
auto min(Head&& h, Args&&... args) -> typename std::common_type<Head, Args...>::type
{
  return fold(p_less(), std::forward<Head>(h), 
              std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


// only considers homogeneous arguments
template<typename Head, typename... Args>
auto hmin(Head&& h, Args&&... args) -> Head
{
  return fold([](Head x, Head y) -> Head { return x < y ? x : y; }, 
              std::forward<Head>(h), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{

  double x = 2.0, x2 = 3.0;
  int y = 2;

  auto d1 = min(3, 4.0, 2.f, 6UL);
  auto d2 = min(x, y);
  auto d3 = hmin(x, x2);
  auto b = hmin(3, 2, 7, 10);

  std::cout << d1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << d2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << d3 << std::endl;

  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The first version is a lot more interesting however. `common_type`
looks for the type that all arguments can be coerced to. This is
necessary because a function with heterogeneous arguments returning
either of them needs to find this type. However, this could be
circumvented using `boost::variant` but for built-in types this is
rather pointless as they have to be coerced to be compared anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. This should be fixed now and the return types as well as argument types of the functor should exactly fit the types that were used as to call `min` with. Although I think it still messes up with mixed lvalue/rvalue arguments but I have no idea how to fix this. Anything else that is still amiss?

Comment: I think in this case the best recourse is actually to pass all arguments as const ref. And if you modify or store the arguments, pass everything by value and hope for the best.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But that would prevent usage such as `min(a, b) = 0` which I would consider somewhat useful.

Comment: True but even `std::min` doesn’t allow this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph So what we have here is an improved `std::min` although at some cost.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
template <typename T, typename... T2>
T min(T x1, T2... rest);

template <typename T>
T min(T x)
{
  return x;
}

template <typename T, typename... T2>
T min(T x1, T2... rest)
{
  return std::min (x1, min (rest...));
}
```

While this doesn't seem to enforce homogenity, calling with e.g. `int` and `long` gives compilation errors.  Unfortunately, I'm not that good at standardese to say if it is supposed to be so.